# Android: Share image with other apps only works partly

Tags: java, android

I am trying to share an image from my drawables with other apps using android's standard way. The code I use to share an image is the following:

```
Uri uriPath = getUriToDrawable(SingleEmojiActivity.this, image);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriPath);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Where `getUriToDrawable()` is the following function:

```
public static final Uri getUriToDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @AnyRes int drawableId) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
            "://" + context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(drawableId)
            + '/' + context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(drawableId)
            + '/' + context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(drawableId) );
    return imageUri;
}
```

The code works, and some of the compatible apps will actually accept the image, but the problem is that other's won't. The image I want to share is a regular png, and I've also tried with jpg, but neither work. I've tested other apps with the ability to share, and they work with those that wouldn't work with my own app. What could be my problem?

Thatnk in advanced!

Edit:

The minSdkVersion I have is 15, and the targetSdkVersion is 23. The actual sdk I have on the device is 22.

Comment: have you tried `sendIntent.setType("image/*");` Also, what kind of apps are these "apps"?

Comment: @BurakDay Yes, but the problem still exists

Comment: Are you talking about facebook, whatsapp or instagram as "apps"?

Comment: `Uri uriPath = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/reflectionafter.png"));
        
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriPath);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        m_activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send"));`            this code works and shows every application on my device

Comment: @BurakDay Exactly, those are the type of apps I mean. It work with about half of them, so I find it weird that those that don't work for me works for others. For example Instagram works, but Whatsapp does not.

Comment: Instantiate the intent as `Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);` and see if anything changes. That's the only remarkable difference between the codes as long as you are producing your uri properly

Comment: @BurakDay I tried it, but unfortunately I got the same problem.

Comment: What's the API level are you working on? Can you update your question with API level and more clues that affect file uri and the intent you are going to fire

Comment: Do you mean by "some application don't work" that there is no such apps in chooser list or they don't work after you clicked on them? Some application can have additional filters, for example to support only file:///, http:// and https:// schemes. Also, are your test devices rooted?

Comment: @VolodymyrBaydalka They appear in the chooser list, but when I click it I get errors. The devices are not rooted. Thank you for telling me about filters, I will look into them.

Comment: If apps are in the list it means that intent filters are OK. Most possible that those apps can't work with resource images from other app or just have no permission to get resources from other apps (it also can be an issue). Try to copy all your images to application folder on sdcard on first start and share images from this folder instead of using package resources.

Comment: @VolodymyrBaydalka Thank you very much. That was actually the problem, and your solution worked as well. Thank again :)